# Type error with Razor, intellisense and lambda expressions

Tags: asp.net, razor, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2012, ASP.NET MVC 4, and Razor views. Consider the following code:

```
@{
    Action<Action<int>> fun = x => { x(42); };
    fun(x =>  { PrintX(x); }); // This is OK
    fun(x =>  { var z = PrintX(x); }); // This produces error
    // "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to
    // 'System.Action<int>'"
}
@helper PrintX(int x) { <div>@x</div> }
```

Somehow adding the characters `var z =` to the contents of a lambda function makes it unable to cast it to the right type (actually, any form of taking the value of that function gives this).

However this error is only produced by IntelliSense. It works in runtime.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Heh, solved it myself. :) The problem was that the method returns a type `System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult`, which is defined in the assembly `System.Web.WebPages`. Unfortunately that assembly wasn't loaded as far as IntelliSense was concerned, so weirdness started happening.

To fix it, all I needed to do was to add the following line to my web.config:

```
<add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
```

(Yes, I'm still using the old MVC 3 after all. My mistake, fixed the question)